# how to redirect all URL's to Single page using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How can i redirect all the urls to one single page and admin to admin-folder-name ??

example

```
http://domainname.com/about should point to redirect.php?url=about
http://domainname.com/contact should point to redirect.php?url=contact
```

But at the same time

```
http://domainname.com/admin should point to admin folder ??
```

My current .htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule (.*) redirect.php?page_url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I'm struck with /admin
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a condition that excludes redirecting /admin:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1 ^/?admin
RewriteRule (.*) redirect.php?page_url=$1 [QSA,L]
```